# ros-indigo package not found

Tags: ros, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following for installing ROS-Indigo on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 (installed in VirtualBox on Windows 10).

After the `sudo apt-get update` command, I tried running the `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full` command, however the following error popped up:

`E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full`.

Further I tried running the following commands as well, but to no avail:

1. `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop`
2. `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-base`

They gave the same `package not found` error.

I searched the Ubuntu 14.04 package list [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/allpackages), and did not seem to find any package related to `ros-indigo`.

Note: I am not much experienced with the Linux environment and would be grateful for any help in this regard.

Thank You

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287721/ros-indigo-package-not-found/) by [codeahead](https://answers.ros.org/users/34511/codeahead/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-06**:
You might have missed a step in the installation tutorials. What is the output of:

```
ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

If there is no file that adds the ROS repositories there, that might be your problem.

Alternatively, something could have gone wrong while importing the key. I'd check that too.

**Comment by [codeahead](https://answers.ros.org/users/34511/codeahead/) on 2018-04-06**:
The output of `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d` is empty, i.e. there is nothing inside the `sources.list.d` directory.

I followed [this](http://f1tenth.org/session1t#tut0) tutorial, and here it creates `opt` dir inside `/etc` and there I can see this file `ros-latest-list`. Does this mean anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend to follow the regular installation tutorial: [wiki/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu).

In any case: there is a typo in the tutorial you link: it should be `apt`, not `opt` (note: `a`, not `o`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [codeahead](https://answers.ros.org/users/34511/codeahead/) on 2018-04-08**:
Thank You for pointing out the typo. The installation works now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
You should probably report that typo to the author(s) of the tutorial you were following.

Without the fix, nothing will ever work.